# Matching items using Android camera

Tags: android, compare, android-camera

I have to recognize an existing item with android camera, but I don't know how to do it.
For example, I want my user to take a photo like this

[image]

then iI want to store my image on the device(this is not a problem) with a name like "Status 1"

and then, I want the user to take another picture like in a different place with different light/ orientation, and I want the device to recognize it as "Status 1", for example, the second photo might be like this:

[image]

I took two random photos from the web so take it as if both were been taken from the same device.

Is it possible? I just want the device to say "It's the same object" or similar when someone asks him if the second picture's item is already existing in the DB.

Sorry if I have no photos but links, but I have not enough points to post images.

Thanks for the attention, I hope I explained it correctly

Comment: You are looking for image recognition. Maybee this API could help you: http://www.snap2life.de/index.php/leistungen/bilderkennung/ ?

Comment: @PhilippEmmermacher i will look for it, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @PhilippEmmermacher i checked it, it says all resources are in a no more existing link, and api page is empty. U know where to find apis or anyone knows another way to do it? thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an online or offline recognition?

Comment: @PhilippEmmermacher both are good, the item i have to recognize is like a key or similar, so is important to identify borders, online or offline are both correct

Comment: The link i posted provides an online recogition api. You can register your own images and query them later. It works very solid but it's not for free. There is a demo application with documentation for iOS in Github.

Comment: Is there any free api for this? since it's a personal use application i prefer not to pay

Comment: I dont think so because image recogntition is not that easy and only a small amount of companies are doing such things. Vuforia from Qualcomm provided a free solution for offline recognition but since a few month they also want money for it.

Comment: thanks you very much, i will check for it also. have a nice day and thanks again :)